# factoring $k^2 + 3k + 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I am teaching something on induction. I always had the identity $k^2 + 3k + 2 = (k + 1)(k + 2)$ memorized.
I want to systematically get that identity the only thing I was able to get is the identity
$$(k + \frac{3}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4}$$

I am proving the summation formula for induction.

Comment: I don't understand.  What's the "summation formula for induction"?  As to factoring, well the quadratic equation easily finds the roots and that's all you need.

Comment: @lulu "I don't understand..." got that right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From there, you can write this as:

$$\left( k + \frac32\right)^2 - \left(\frac12\right)^2$$

This is the difference of two squares. Something of the form $a^2 - b^2$. Does that ring any bells?

Comment: Right. I didn't notice that at all!

Answer (score 1):

You can factorize like this $$k^2+3k+2=k^2+2k+k+2$$ $$=k(k+2)+k+2$$ $$=(k+2)(k+1).$$

Answer (score 0):

I will highjack lulu's comment.

If $Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$, then

$$x = \frac{1}{2A}\left(-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}\right).$$

In the present example, you have

$$A=1, B=3, C=2.$$

Therefore

$$x = \frac{1}{2}\left(-3 \pm \sqrt{9^2 - 8}\right).$$

This translates to

$$x = -2 ~\text{or}~ x = -1.$$

This means that the factors are

$$[x - (-2)] ~\text{and} ~[x - (-1)].$$

Answer (score 0):

We put $f(k) =k^2+3k+2$

$f(-1)=0$ $ \Rightarrow$ $ f(k) = (k+1)(k+2)$